# De-Rham cohomology and manifold theory.

Tags: homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

So I've been working on my geometry homework, and have a question: 
Problem:
Let $M=S^{1} \times S^{2}$, with free-involution $\tau: (z,x) \mapsto (\bar{z},-x).$ Let $N=M/\tau$ be the quotient manifold. Identify the action of $\tau$ on $H^{p}_{dR}(M)$ and use the fact that $H_{dR}^{p}(N)$ is isomorphic to $H_{dR}^{p}(M)^{\tau}$ to compute $H_{dR}^{p}(N)$.

So, here the free involution $\tau$ is acting on $M$ by conjugating $z \in S^{1}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in S^{2}$ by mapping its antipodal points: $x \mapsto -x$. But, since $H^{p}_{dR}(M)^{\tau}=\{[\alpha] \in H^{p}_{dR}(M): \tau^{*}[\alpha]=[\alpha]\}$ is the subspace of $H^{p}_{dR}(M)$ fixed by the induced action $\tau$ on $H^{p}_{dR}(M)$, I want to consider the tangent space

$TM=T(S^{1}\times S^{2})$. This is because the diffeomorphic map $\theta:M \to M$ induces $\theta^{*}:TM^{*} \leftarrow TM^{*}$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any hints, of course, are much apprecited. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to represent elements in $H^p_{dR}(M)$ explicitly?

Comment: @JohnMa If you mean by closed forms modulo exact forms? Also,  the deRham cohomology of the  direct product of $S^{1} \times S^{2}$ is not necessarily the product of the deRham cohomology of $S^{1}$ direct product of the deRham cohomology of $S^{2}$. Only if $M$ is the disjoint union of the $S^{1}$ with $S^{2}$. But I cannot determine what $H^{p}_{dR}(M)$ is explicitly.

Comment: Indeed $H^k(M) = \bigoplus_{i+j = k} H^i(\mathbb S^1) \otimes H^j(\mathbb S^2)$, that's Kunneth formula. Do you know how to represent  the cohomology of $\mathbb S^1$ and $\mathbb S^2$ explicitly? By explicit, I mean (explicitly) writing down a form in each class.

Comment: Aside from the usual general $f=f_{I}dx_{I}$, no.

Comment: So what did you learn? What tools can you use?\